# Sum a Subtotal in MS Access by Date

Tags: ms-access, report

I'm using MS Access 2010

My query has the fields, Date, Market Price, Actual Price

I need to separate out within the query by date Actual Price/Market Price in order to achieve a percentage which I can then average *(for that day only, one day at a time)*

Each day will have anywhere from 10-50 items.

Comment: what have you tried? please also post some sample data and your expected result.

Comment: Try the query design window. Use the help button and the wizards.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a standard query, but a totals to the query. On the Home tab, in the Records group, click Totals.

Once you have that field displayed you can put a Sum (in the Totals field) for Market Price and Actual Price; and then make sure the Date field is set to GroupBy.

Then you should be getting totals for the Price fields grouped by Date.

btw., I'd label that date field something else other than just Date (e.g., DateSold, PurchaseDate, etc.) just to avoid confusion and possible conflicts with the Date type.

Comment: Thank you Code Slave! That helped. I also figured out that the hours, minutes, seconds were factoring into the equation and messing up the averages for some reason. I removed those with a custom DropTime function, summed the amounts for each date and averaged them out.